# Debugging HTTPS ASP.NET site in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, ssl, https

How do other people debug HTTPS sites from Visual Studio 2008?  [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60113/https-with-visual-studios-built-in-asp-net-develpment-server) seems to indicate that Visual Studio's built in web server does not support HTTPS, but there must be some way to debug these sites, right?  If not the integrated server, can IIS7 be set as the debugging web server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you may set IIS as the debugging server by clicking `Properties` on the project, (waiting patiently while it slowly loads), then go to the `Web` tab and choose `Use IIS Web server` instead of `Use Visual Studio Development Server`.

-- Edit

More generally, to answer the question, I typically just disable SSL while debugging. It's rare that I need to test how I'm dealing with things via SSL, and depending on how I'm creating the SSL links, it can be modified pretty simply, with an `#if DEBUG`.

Comment: using an #if DEBUG is a good idea ... I'll give that a shot, thanks.

Comment: @Beepbeep, "#if DEBUG" only works if you're sure to deploy a different configuration to production