# ASP.NET MVC RequireHttps

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl, asp.net-mvc-2, https, asp.net-mvc-futures

How do I use the ASP.NET MVC 2 Preview 2 Futures RequireHttps attribute?

I want to prevent unsecured HTTP requests from being sent to an action method.  I want to automatically redirect to HTTPS.

MSDN:

- [RequireHttpsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.requirehttpsattribute(VS.100).aspx)
- [RequireHttpsAttribute Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.requirehttpsattribute_members(VS.100).aspx)
- [RequireHttpsAttribute.HandleNonHttpsRequest Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.requirehttpsattribute.handlenonhttpsrequest(VS.100).aspx)

How do I use this feature?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My guess:

```
[RequireHttps] //apply to all actions in controller
public class SomeController 
{
  //... or ...
  [RequireHttps] //apply to this action only
  public ActionResult SomeAction()
  {
  }

}
```

Comment: That does seem to prevent HTTP requests, but it doesn't redirect to HTTPS.

Comment: No. This might just be a problem with Visual Studio's ASP.NET Development Server. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60113/

Comment: ASP.NET MVC RequireHttps in Production Only: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639707/asp-net-mvc-requirehttps-in-production-only

Comment: might be a basic question , as read [here](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12531/ssl-with-get-and-post) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499591/are-https-urls-encrypted) `post` request also get encrypted, 

but like to know weather i should decorate `RequireHttps` in post also ?

Answer (score 16):

I think you're going to need to roll your own `ActionFilterAttribute` for that.

```
public class RedirectHttps : ActionFilterAttribute {
   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection) {
            filterContext.Result = 
                new RedirectResult(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.
                    ToString().Replace("http:", "https:"));
            filterContext.Result.ExecuteResult(filterContext);
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Then in your controller :

```
public class HomeController : Controller {

    [RedirectHttps]
    public ActionResult SecuredAction() {
        return View();
    }
}
```

You might want to read [this](http://blog.tylergarlick.com/index.php/2009/07/mvc-redirect-to-http-and-https/) as well.

Comment: Be careful when adding this to an action that is intended for the POST method.

Comment: @Carl why? because the post data is lost? If you want to ensure that sensitive data not being posted over non https, then you shouldn't process that data.

Comment: @çağdaş You may want to use this method to change the scheme - should be safer than a string replace: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968426/changing-the-scheme-of-system-uri