# How can I configure my MVC 3 app to use HTTP on login and HTTPS on the rest of the pages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, http, https

How can I configure my ASP.NET MVC 3 application to use HTTP on login and HTTPS on the rest of the pages?

Now I configured the app to use HTTPS on every page including Login.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks a lot.

Jeff

Comment: Why would you want to run the login over regular HTTP when you have the option to do it over HTTPS?

Comment: You really don't want to do this, your users would be sending their passwords over the internet in clear text.

Comment: I think he means it the other way around. I would like to do the same.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574347/asp-net-mvc-requirehttps

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in `RequireHttpsAttribute` see [the documentation reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.requirehttpsattribute.aspx)

You can set this on your controller class like this:

```
[RequireHttps]
public Controller HomeController() { }
```

All actions of this controller will use Https.

Or directly on a controller action

```
[RequireHttps]
public ActionResult Index() { }
```

You may also register this for the entire app on your global.asax

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
  filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
  filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
}
```