# SSL with Visual Studio Development Server

Tags: ssl

Is it possible to use SSL with Visual Studio Development Server (a.k.a. Web Application project)?  I don't want to have to deploy IIS locally if possible.  I'm running Windows 7.

NOTE: I've seen this (http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/354576/add-https-support-to-visual-studio-asp-net-development-server) but I was still hoping there was a workaround.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTTPS with Visual Studio's built-in ASP.NET Development Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60113/https-with-visual-studios-built-in-asp-net-development-server)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It cannot be done with VS 2008, so I've simply resorted to deploying my app to the local IIS as part of the start process with a generated cert.

Comment: Not expecting that it would have unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

We can use IIS Express with VS 2010 to develope and test web apps in SSL. Here is a complete article explaning how to use IIS Express and Visual Studion 2010 to develope websites in SSL

[Working with SSL at Development Time is easier with IISExpress](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx)

[Introducing IIS Express](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

this subject was covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60113/https-with-visual-studios-built-in-asp-net-develpment-server) and it say's, you actually can't.

But you might take a look at this link, which might prove the contrary: *(See link in comment, i'm not yet able to post more then 1 link per post ...doh)*

Hope this helps.

Comment: Here is the missing link: http://omni-foundation.net/blog/blog1.php/2008/10/31/visual-studio-development-server-and-htt

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in VS2010, I'm not sure if VS2008 supports the following approach. Configure Visual Studio to use use Microsoft IIS Express instead of the web server built in to Visual Studio.