# Url.Action not including port number

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, https

I have a partial view which is displayed on a non-HTTPS page, but POSTS to a controller that requires SSL.  The form definition is this:

```
        <form id="authForm"
          method="post"
          action="@Url.Action("authenticate", "auth", new {}, "https")">
```

The problem I'm having is that, within Visual Studio and when debugging, the host and port are `localhost:64043`.  However, the `Url.Action` call above doesn't put the port number in, meaning the browser directs to my IIS installation.  Do I have to add something else, or override this method?  I want my application to be location agnostic.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could include it like this:

```
@Url.Action(
    "authenticate", 
    "auth", 
    null, 
    "https", 
    Request.Url.Host + ":" + Request.Url.Port
)
```

Of course this means that your local web server must support SSL which is not the case with Cassini. You could use [IIS Express](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/868/iis-express-overview/) for this to work.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for this.  Turns out IIS Express was already installed.  However, the issue I am having now is that although IIS shows an Express certificate installed, I get `Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with the server or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have.` as an error when it tries to post the form...  argh!

Answer (score 0):

The integrated development server does not support HTTPS, but you can use your local IIS - see [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60113/https-with-visual-studios-built-in-asp-net-development-server).

Answer (score 0):

Http and https connections are usually on two different ports so if you change from one protocol to the other you either need to use the standard port or supply a specific port yourself. There's no sensible way a generic system can determine the right port

Answer (score 0):

Use `Request.Host.ToUriComponent()`:

`string actionUrl = Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { blah = "" }, Request.Scheme, Request.Host.ToUriComponent());`

This also correctly omits the port number when it is the default port for the scheme, i.e if the Scheme is HTTP and the port is 80, or the Scheme is HTTPS and the port is 443, it will be omitted.