# How to test my ASP.NET page on https://localhost in a development environment?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, ssl, https, localhost

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTTPS with Visual Studio's built-in ASP.NET Development Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60113/https-with-visual-studios-built-in-asp-net-development-server)

I'm writing a C#, ASP.NET web application with the VS 2010 IDE. I do not have the IIS server installed on this Windows 7 machine. All my testing of the web app goes through the "ASP.NET Development Server" that came with Visual Studio 2010. My pages usually load into the web browser with an adress like this: "http://localhost:59215/Default.aspx"

So my question is, can I test it with a HTTPS URL?

And if yes, can someone give me steps?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 with SP1 now has IIS Express, which will allow you run on SSL.

See here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx

You can also create a self-signed certificate to avoid any issues with buying a certificate.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/06/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates.aspx

Comment: +1 Haven't had a need to do this yet and didn't realize they made changes to make it easier.

Comment: @Inturbidus Yes, thanks for the heads-up, although I can't seem to enable IIS Express on my web app project that was created prior to SP1. That's pretty lame. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: OK, I figured it out. To use that IIS Express one needs to download it. In other words it doesn't come with SP1. You can get it from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1038