# Enabling SSL in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

In VS 2015 when clicking on the properties tab of the project there was an SSL box that could be set to true or false. I can't find the same thing in VS 2017. 
Anyone know?

Cheers.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The SSL setting is at a different place in ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core projects. The following screenshots come from my blog: https://www.meziantou.net/2016/10/09/iis-express-ssl

**ASP.NET**

[image]

**ASP.NET Core**

[image]

Comment: Hi. Found it. By right clicking in the project and click properties it gives me something similar to what you have in example two but without SSL....but going to the tab at the top and click Views --> Properties gets me the little properties box from example 1. Thanks

Comment: there is no longer a 'debug' tab for the ASP.Net Core.  Enable SSL must have been moved elsewhere.

Comment: The debug tab is still present in the latest version of Visual Studio 2017 for ASP.NET Core 2.0 projects

Comment: In order to get this to work, you then have to click 'Properties' on your application, go to the Web tab and override the Project URL with the one provided when you enable SSL, then restart your VS solution, or it won't invoke the URL

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 - Open project properties
[image]
Step 2 - Set launch from 'Project' to 'IIS'
[image]
Step 3 - Click on Enable SSL
[image]
Step 4 - Copy the HTTPS URL
[image]
Step 5 - Switch back to project and paste the url
[image]