# How To Disable Https in Visual Studio 2017 Web Proj ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, iis-express, asp.net-core-2.0

I've created a default project in Visual Studio 2017 with ASP.NET Core 2.0. I've chosen the Web App with MVC and with Individual Use Auth.  By default, it is coming up configured and working with https. I've tried disabling that by going into project properties and removing the user ssl and changing https to http but then I get either and IIS Express Connection error or a 404.

I've not see default https before.  Where is that coming from and where can I disable it?

Comment: For .net framework see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43886999/939213

Answer (score 54):

**Update .Net 6**

If you stumbled across this question, but are looking to disable SSL in .Net 6, follow these instructions:

1. Disable SSL redirection by removing `app.UseHttpsRedirection();`
2. (optional) define a default port to listen to with `app.Run("http://localhost:5000");` If omitted, a random port will be assigned.

**Original answer for .Net Core 2.0:**

I've just created a default MVC app using net core 2.0.

To disable SSL, you need to do 2 steps. You can do this either by using the Visual Studio GUI, or by editing the launchsettings.json (further down)

- go to your project properties
- In the Debug category uncheck the SSL option
- Copy the App Url over to the Start browser input
  [image]

Et voila:

[image]

If you are not a fan of using the interface, you can alternatively edit the launchsettings.json file, by setting `sslPort: 0` and `"launchUrl": "http://localhost:13121/"` (or where ever you want to launch the application)

```js
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:13121/",
      "sslPort": 0 
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "http://localhost:13121/",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "WebApplication1": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:13122/"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Although this works, when I log in to my site, it successfully logs me in, but then never sets the auth cookie which means I can't access Admin pages

Comment: Tipp: The launchUrl accepts relative URLs, so you actually don't have to copy the scheme and host there. Just enter / oder leave it empty.

Comment: it looks like once sslPort is set, iisexpress won't go back to http after the sslPort is set to 0 again.

Comment: So this is yet another Microsoft bug in Visual Studio?  It just gets worse every upgrade. ugh!

Comment: How can we disable it on mac?

Answer (score 16):

I was just having this same issue (ie. I needed a non-SSL URL to establish a working ngrok.com tunnel)

## There's probably an alternative unsecured localhost URL defined.

I realize the question is to disable the secured one, but you probably don't need to. **You probably already have an unsecured one defined.**

Admittedly, I inherited this project so I'm not aware if a default project would be configured the same. My assumption is that there's an unsecured URL already available for you that you might be overlooking.

- If I'm wrong this answer seems good ([Ngrok errors '502 bad gateway'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40598428/ngrok-errors-502-bad-gateway/48965144#answer-46261481)), but again I didn't need to try it.

### Just look in the "Development Server" properties.

#### See my screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Downvoted because question is about ASP.NET _Core_ and answer is about ASP.NET (Framework)

Comment: Upvoted because I wasn't looking for an answer relating to ASP.NET *Core*, and wanted to find an answer about ASP.NET (Framework). Unfortunately, even having set the `Enable SSL` setting to *False*, the damn thing keeps trying to open on HTTPS which I don't have set up so this hasn't helped anyway.

Comment: instead of hiding parts of the image please consider to use dummy project to point to the information if the name of the project is so sensitive, otherwise don't put images at all and use text only for instructions

Comment: @EslamBadawy The instructions were "Just look in the "Development Server" properties." So the image should only add to that...

Comment: Where do you find the "Development Server" properties? I have the same problem - VS insists on SSL and SSL is not defined anywhere.

Comment: never mind. Dotnet Core apps don't have this feature.

Answer (score 13):

[image: Go to App Properties and uncheck "Enable SSL"]

Go to App Properties and uncheck "Enable SSL"

Comment: Unfortunately, this no longer works in Visual Studio. It's an unresolved bug that MS refuses to admit.

Answer (score 0):

If the answer provided by @Marco didn't resolved the issue you can try this,

When you create new .net core mvc application there will be default meta tag generated in _Layout cshtml to upgrade the http request to https ( "http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests"). When you deploy your application to server without http you may need to remove the below tags

http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests"

Also comment the below line from Startup.cs file

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely in your publish settings.

I had this issue and I simply went to the publish settings and discovered that after the build, the publish url contained https.