# How to configure Visual Studio 2017 to expose a non-encrypted port in a ASP.Net MVC https site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, https, ngrok

I'm trying to test webhooks from Stripe.com on my locahost (dev machine) using Visual Studio 2017. My site uses https. In order to test webhooks, you need a url, so on my local machine I have to install and use ngrok. Ngrok gives me a url to provide to Stripe so stripe knows where to send the post request. The problem is ngrok doesn't work with https!

I've been looking for a solution for 2 days and I've emailed ngrok to ask, they replied with

> you *should* be able to configure VS to expose a non-encrypted port but i'm not super familiar with it in a way that I can tell you how to go about doing it. maybe the ngrok VS extension will help? https://ngrok.com/docs#visual-studio

I've already tried running the extension. No luck! All it does is open up the ngrok.exe and runs it.

So I'm trying to see if it's possible to open/expose a non-encrypted port? I assume this means a action method or controller using http and NOT https?

Or does it mean something else? Is this possible in ASP.NET MVC???

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get my ASP.NET Core MVC project to accept test Stripe webhooks calls this morning using ngrok in VS 2017 running on IIS Express.

I had to do two things:

1. Turn off `app.UseHttpsRedirection()` when testing.  I modified my `Startup.Configure(..)` to only use HTTP redirection when not in development like this:

   ```
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
   {
       if (env.IsDevelopment())
       {               
           // <snip>
       }
       else
       {
           // <snip>
           app.UseHttpsRedirection(); // <- Moved from outside to inside else block to allow ngrok tunneling for testing Stripe webhooks
       }

       // <snip>
       app.UseMvc();
   }
   ```
2. Start ngrok tunneling using the non-HTTPS URL for the website.  In my case, my project is configured to use the following ports:

   ```
     <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:64768:localhost" />
     <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44358:localhost" />
   ```

   So my ngrok command is this:

   ```
   ngrok http 64768 -host-header="localhost:64768"
   ```

Hope this helps someone - I too struggled for awhile to get this to work.

Answer (score -1):

**See my answer here:** [How To Disable Https in Visual Studio 2017 Web Proj ASP.NET Core 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46507029/how-to-disable-https-in-visual-studio-2017-web-proj-asp-net-core-2-0/48964959#answer-48964959)

**Note: If I'm wrong about there being a default unsecured URL,** the question above has a solution for disabling the secured URL. I didn't try it because there was already an unsecured URL defined in my existing project (as I suspect there is with yours as well)

- Also, this answer seems good ([Ngrok errors '502 bad gateway'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40598428/ngrok-errors-502-bad-gateway/48965144#answer-46261481)), but again I didn't need to try it.

## Just use the established unsecured URL instead of the secured one.

[image]