# Can't find where to enable SSL in VS2017 ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I am having an ASP.NET application (not core) and I can't find where to enable SSL. It's not showing up in the Project Properties, neither I have a Debug tab(like in core).

Neither of this show up:
[Enabling SSL in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43886818/enabling-ssl-in-visual-studio-2017])

[image][image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43886818/enabling-ssl-in-visual-studio-2017

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enabling SSL in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43886818/enabling-ssl-in-visual-studio-2017)

Comment: i'm guessing this will only enable it in debug mode, which is kinda pointless because no one is sniffing your packets in debug mode. Once you publish it, it becomes a setting on the web server

Answer (score 1):

1. In **`Solution Explorer`** (**Ctrl** + **Alt** + **L**) window select your project.
2. In **`Properties`** (**F4**) window find `SSL Enabled` option.

Comment: just use hotkeys

Answer (score 1):

Go to  `Solution Explorer` -> `Properties` -> `Debug` -> `Web Server Settings` and set `Enable SSL`.

[image]