# I am not not able run an website in localhost

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, localhost

This site can’t provide a secure connection localhost sent an invalid response.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Comment: Seems like sam issue already solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43338665/this-site-can-t-provide-a-secure-connection
Hope it helps.

Comment: sorry to say this, answer is no...

Answer (score 0):

When running a service or site locally you can avoid this problem by doing the following:

1. In project properties enable SSL:

[image]

2. Make sure to put https link  as a start URL or just make direct request to https version:

[image]