# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR for localhost from Visual Studio debug

Tags: asp.net, .net, google-chrome, iis, iis-express

I am running a simple ASP.net web application. Chrome is showing the below error after running this.

```
localhost sent an invalid response.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

but my application is on http, not https.

[image]

but the URL is loading with `https://localhost:54056/`

config is also pointing to http only.

```
 <site name="tan-square" id="2">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\Myfolder\OneDrive\Downloads\tan-square" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:54056:localhost" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
```

I don't understand where the problem is. Why is it loading with https?

Comment: What if you switch to another web browser? Chrome has been insane on pushing its own restrictions (on certificates and so on), so really not a good browser for debugging.

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43338665/this-site-can-t-provide-a-secure-connection

Answer (score 110):

First, check your site web binding detail by the following detail:

1. Open visual studio, select your project.
2. right-click on the project and select properties.
3. under the Web tab and check your project url.

[image]

make sure there no such setting in your web.conifg file like below:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Strict-Transport-Security" 

        value="max-age=16070400; includeSubDomains" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

When the browser sees this, it will remember, for the given number of seconds, that the current domain should only be contacted over HTTPS. In the future, if the user types http:// or omits the scheme, HTTPS is the default.

Clear your browser cache.

Another thing you could try to find the cause is open chrome and type `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` in the address bar (in edge type `edge://net-internals/#hsts`) and search for `localhost`:

[image]

The query shows “localhost” as being in the list of domains in the HSTS set.

The solution is deleting the domain from the cache. type “localhost” into the Delete domain text field, and hit Delete. After doing that when you query for “localhost” again you will receive a “Not found”.

[image]

Comment: I did the chrome thing and it worked for me. Thanks!!

Comment: For me, clearing chrome cache solved this issue.

Comment: Perfect! Nothing else worked for me.

Comment: Removing localhost from HSTS prison did the trick for me! Nothing else was working!!! Thanks!!!

Comment: I am running an .net 6 web project In VS2022 and there is no section 'Web' in the project settings.

Comment: In my Startup.cs: #if !DEBUG
context.Response.Headers.TryAdd("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=60");     
#endif

Comment: Dame bro you are my hero ,Cleaning localhost from chrome list solved my issue , I tested HSTS in localhost , somehow a month later I confronted this issue (I did it a long ago) and suddenly I had this issue interestingly . A lot of thanks for help .

Answer (score 5):

**Just create new Virtual Directory:**

1-right-click on the project and select properties.

2-under the Web tab change your project url by changing the localhost to http://localhost:48333/ .

3- click Create Virtual Directory.

4- make sure you don't have this in **web.config**

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=16070400; includeSubDomains"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: This is by far the most simple solution. Just remember to be sure that your Web.confg transform is proper as show in the example above by Jalapa_Panchal.

Answer (score 2):

In my case "clearing SSL State" has solved my issue.

- Open the Start menu.
- Search for and open Internet Options.
- In the dialog box that appears, select the Content tab.
- Click Clear SSL State.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running **.net core**, just run Visual Studio as admin, or go to bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1  directory, and issue. Wierdly, .net core. .net core surprisingly dont give any error.

```
%USERPROFILE%\\.dotnet\\tools\\dotnet-lambda-test-tool-3.1.exe --port 5059
```

change port number to whatever.

Comment: Interestingly running VS as admin solved the problem for me, then subsequently running VS without elevated privileges the browser no longer reported the error.

Answer (score 1):

Go to launch settings
change the launch URL to https instead of http,
it will ask you to add self generated ssl ,
click Yes and it Run the project.
Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

VS will do this automatically if you add an ssl port to the iisbindings section of launchsettings.json. There is no UI to do it but you can edit the file directly.

```
{
    "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iis": {
        "applicationUrl": "https://localhost/WebApplication",
        "sslPort": 443
    },
    "iisExpress": {
        "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:62686",
        "sslPort": 44391
    }
},
```

Answer (score -4):

Change default browser to Chrome and the issue is solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).