# URL path to the MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC application, I try to run the application but I can not get any page in Browser, I am guessing the path has some problem.

This is RouteConfig:

```
      public class RouteConfig {
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.ashx/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default", // Route name
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
    }
}
```

This is HomeController:

```
   public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to DevExpress Extensions for ASP.NET MVC!";

        return View();
    }
```

This is the View's path:

Views -> Home -> Index.cshml

```
 @Html.DevExpress().ReportDesigner(settings =>
  {
    settings.Name = "ReportDesigner";
   }).Bind(new DevExpressDemo.Reports.Report1()).GetHtml()



  This URL is in Project URL: http://localhost:53975/
```

When I run the project I go to this URL:

```
    https://localhost:53975/Home/Index
```

But this is the response I am getting in Browser:

```
 This site can’t provide a secure connectionlocalhost sent an invalid response.
```

When I go to http://localhost:53975/ it convert it automatically to https and shows : This site can’t provide a secure connection

Comment: Have you tried to change the project URL? Right click your project name in the Solution Explorer, Select Properties, click the Web tab and change the https to http in the project url

Comment: Is this running in Visual Studio or IIS?

Comment: @mxmissile using build in IIS is visual Studio.

Comment: @Eric - In project property is http but when I run it is https, and even if I change the URL in browser, it will back to https.

Comment: which visual studio version 2019?

Comment: @Eric - Yes 2019

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60558382/err-ssl-protocol-error-for-localhost-from-visual-studio-debug check this link out you might have something in your web.config file that is setting this

Comment: Also you can click on your project in the solution explorer and click F4, make sure that SSL Enabled is false when the Properties window shows up. If this doesn't work either I would have to say it has to be something in the web.config file

Comment: If none of that works it could possibly be the User report designer for Devexpress when you bind their DevExpressDemo.Reports.Report1()

Comment: @Eric - maybe that id DevExpress thing! I made SSL enable and Use SSL URL and it worked!

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to access it through https rather than http. Go to `http://localhost:53975` in your browser and see if that works.

Comment: even if I type http it automatically goes to https and shows This site can’t provide a secure connection.

Answer (score -1):

change HTTPS to HTTP on yourr brrowser address bar