# use https on asp.net application running on localhost

Tags: asp.net, ssl, iis, https

I've created an asp.net web application with a web form called "Main.aspx" in it. I'm trying to run the application over https. Since I have no experiences with SSL, IIS etc. I googled how to achieve this but every solution didn't work for me.

I enabled SSL using the following steps: [Enable SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8817682/2679160)

My application is now running on https://localhost:59917/.

[image]

But if I start my application I get a Firefox error message: "Secure connection failed". So I followed the steps from [Scott Gu's Blog Post](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates) but it didn't work neither.

Does anyone have experiences in SSL and ASP.net web applications and can help me out?

Comment: This is a programming QA site, not an infrastructure one. You should post this on Server Fault instead

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Since it has something to do with a **C# asp.net web application** it affects programming.

Comment: No, you are not asking how to configure ASP.NET through c#, you are asking how to configure your development server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you followed the instructions, you should have configured your website on the port **443**.

You should configure the binding on port **59917**

Comment: If I try https: //localhost:443/Main.aspx it ends in a 404 not found error message.

Comment: Did you do the binding part of Scott Gu's Blog Post ? Can you please provide the configuration of your local IIS ?

Comment: Yes I added the binding. But with your answer you pointed me in the right direction. I added the binding on port 443 as you said. I now added a binding on port 59917 and it works now! Thx