# MVC5 Azure AD IDX21323

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-5, single-sign-on

My Azure Free subscription has expired. I've since been added to my companies Azure subscription but I can no longer use SSO with Oauth2 using AD.

VS2017 reports 0 subscriptions and when I go to Manage my subscription is listed, but I cannot enable it "This subscription is not supported by server explorer."

I'm assuming that I need to update something on our companies Azure subscription at this point, but I don't know what to request from management as far as subscription updates.

This worked flawlessly before my free subscription ran out.

I've tried the following SO questions:

Use Kentor.OwinCookieSaver:
[IDX21323 OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null, OpenIdConnectProtocolValidatedIdToken.Paylocad.Nonce was not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49944071/idx21323-openidconnectprotocolvalidationcontext-nonce-was-null-openidconnectpro)

[IDX21323 OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null, OpenIdConnectProtocolValidatedIdToken.Paylocad.Nonce was not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49944071/idx21323-openidconnectprotocolvalidationcontext-nonce-was-null-openidconnectpro)

I've tried the following Microsoft Doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/vs-active-directory-add-connected-service

I created a new MVC5 project and added the azure AD connected service with the same result.

I also cleared my cookies, and performed a "Clean" in VS2017.

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri
            });
    }
```

Here is my exception:
Server Error in '/' Application.

IDX21323: RequireNonce is '[PII is hidden]'. OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null, OpenIdConnectProtocol.ValidatedIdToken.Payload.Nonce was not null. The nonce cannot be validated. If you don't need to check the nonce, set OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.RequireNonce to 'false'. Note if a 'nonce' is found it will be evaluated.

*** UPDATE ***

I also tried this, and I think I identified part of the issue, but I still don't have a solution...

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect/wiki/The-'nonce'-found-in-the-jwt-token-did-not-match-the-expected-nonce

From the source code in the above link:
Method Call: MyOpenIDConnectAuthenticationHandler.RetrieveNonce(Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectMessage message)

Line:
string nonceCookie = Request.Cookies[nonceKey];
OwinRequest.Cookies is empty...

I also updated all of my Owin Packages from version 4.0 to 4.1 with no change.

Answer (score 1):

The error above happens when the request to the application does not contain the nonce cookie.You can use the instruction below to capture a Fiddler trace containing the error.

http://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2018/09/12/capture-https-traffic-with-http-fiddler/

Additionally try something like below:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions()
    {
        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
        {
            AuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> authFailed =>
            {
                if (authFailed.Exception.Message.Contains("IDX21323"))
                {
                    authFailed.HandleResponse();
                    authFailed.OwinContext.Authentication.Challenge();
                }

                await Task.FromResult(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

Additional reference:

[IDX21323 OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null, OpenIdConnectProtocolValidatedIdToken.Paylocad.Nonce was not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49944071/idx21323-openidconnectprotocolvalidationcontext-nonce-was-null-openidconnectpro)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I ended up using this implementation. It helps, but it doesn't work in all cases.

I believe I identified the root cause of my issue:
I was sleeping my laptop at the end of my work day. I took it home, connected it to my network, and brought it back into work the following day. 
Restarting my laptop after getting the nonce exception resolves the issue.

This is obviously only for debugging code locally on my laptop, I have yet to put my application into production.

Comment: Hi Slacker what was the solution for this?