# IDX21323 OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null

Tags: google-chrome, azure-active-directory, samesite

Trying to create patch work for same site cookie issue in chrome 80 beta version

**Reference** :https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/upcoming-samesite-cookie-changes-in-asp-net-and-asp-net-core/

Steps done till now:

1. upgraded owin to 4.1
2. upgraded .net framework to 4.72
3. Added sameCookieManager as mentioned in Reference link

startup.cs

```
 var options = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = authority,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
            RedirectUri = redirectUri,
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                SaveSigninToken=true
            },
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
            {
                AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                SecurityTokenValidated = OnSecurityTokenValidated
            },
            CookieManager = new SameSiteCookieManager(new SystemWebCookieManager())

        };
```

It ends up in OnAuthenticationFailed with error "IDX21323 OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null, OpenIdConnectProtocolValidatedIdToken.Paylocad.Nonce was not null"

Tried Few bypass methods mentioned in links below but it didn't work

[MVC5 Azure AD IDX21323](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58205671/mvc5-azure-ad-idx21323)

Comment: Can you validate that you are setting the SameSite flag to None when the cookies are set? Fiddler will show it on the redirect from your site to AAD.

Comment: @HirschSinghal yes it does show that error A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://login.microsoftonline.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute.

Comment: There will be one for your own site as well.  The login.microsoftonline.com one is not the issue here.  Look for a cookie in Fiddler set by your app like "openid.nonce"

Comment: @HirschSinghal whem im debugging cookies in app_start > endrequest method im able to see openid.nonce cookie set with samesite=none , can see it in fidler as well

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @BillMartin there was a patch update done in laptops which resolved this issue. not sure what was the change