# Microsoft login issue in asp.net mvc 5 custom application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service, single-sign-on

Microsoft login issue in asp.net mvc 5 custom application
I have developed ASP.NET MVC 5 custom application.
Basically I want implement Microsoft login functionality SSO (Single Sign On) into that, I have developed Microsoft login custom code into application. When I deployed it on Azure AD app and tested it, login is not working. It is redirecting again again to login page and throws below error:

> IDX21323: RequireNonce is 'System.Boolean'. OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null, OpenIdConnectProtocol.ValidatedIdToken.Payload.Nonce was not null. The nonce cannot be validated. If you don't need to check the nonce, set OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.RequireNonce to 'false'. Note if a 'nonce' is found it will be evaluated.

I have download the sample project from Azure AD App Quickstart option and tested it.
But when I updated it as per my requirement and deployed it on Azure AD app then test it, it behaves same and throws same error.

So how can I achieve Microsoft Login into my custom application or how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Could you please help me with the link of sample project .

Comment: Hey @AjayKumarGhose-MT , You can download sample project using below steps: login to [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/) -> go to "Azure Active Directory" -> select "App Registrations" from left menu -> select your AAD app -> then go to the "Quickstart" menu -> click on start under "Web application" -> select a platform "ASP.NET" -> click on "Download the code sample" button

Answer (score 0):

Reproducing the environment does not gave me the error .The  error may be due to missing nonce cookie.

[Fiddler trace](https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2018/09/capture-https-traffic-with-http-fiddler/) will help in capturing the instruction that contain the error.

Check the  [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58205671/mvc5-azure-ad-idx21323) for further details . And [MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/459819/microsoft-login-issue-in-aspnet-mvc-5-custom-appli.html) where you have already a discuss for this same issue.