# Removing CallbackPath from OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions gives IDX21323 Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory, owin

I am trying to authenticate My Asp.Net MVC Web Application using Axure Active Directory and following instruction given on Microsoft site
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-asp-webapp.

I was facing error:
Server Error in '/MyWebFileDirectory' Application.
"**IDX21323: RequireNonce is '[PII is hidden]'. OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null**".

So I added callbackpath
CallbackPath = new PathString("/MyWebFileDirectory/signin-azuread-oidc").

Now IDX21323 Error gone. but it It always redirect to my Homepage if i try to access any action method with Authorize attribute. So it is authenticating every time and redirecting to home page.

Looking for fix here.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

Check the URL mentioned in the AD App Registrations --> Settings --> Reply URL's. if for example that url is : **https://localhost:44348/**

Go to MVC Project --> Properties (Right Click and Properties) --> Web Section --> Start URL and Project URL should also be : **https://localhost:44348/**

**Solution 2:**

The error may  happens when the request to the application does not contain the nonce cookie

```
Try with this code
      app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions()
    {
        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
        {
            AuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> authFailed =>
            {
                if (authFailed.Exception.Message.Contains("IDX21323"))
                {
                    authFailed.HandleResponse();
                    authFailed.OwinContext.Authentication.Challenge();
                }

                await Task.FromResult(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

For more details refer this [SO-Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58205671/mvc5-azure-ad-idx21323)