# Start a light web server from C# with SSL/TLS HTTPS - without installing certificate / using netsh?

Tags: c#, ssl, web, https, server

Looking to see if there is a way to start a web server with HTTPS support from C# that does not require installing the certificate into windows with netsh. Just a simple lightweight server that can load up a certificate and/or create one at runtime. I just need to be able to read the URL requests and return the content programmatically based on that.

Built-in .NET and third party suggestions are welcome! I haven't been able to find anything.

Bonus points if no administrator permissions are needed as well (avoiding using netsh to add the port namespace)

Thank you!

Clarification edit: I need to start the web server self-contained on a specific port from a C# Desktop Windows application, without using IIS.

Comment: Unsure what you're after so, wouldn't [Visual Studio suffice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8817682/304683)?

Comment: is IIS an option?

Comment: Ah, no I'm not trying to build an HTTPS website in Visual Studio, but launch a self-contained web server from a C# Windows Desktop application, without IIS. Hope this helps clarify.

Comment: Your question is probably more ontopic for [Softwarerecs.se]

Comment: Oh, good suggestion - thanks!

Comment: Posted over there https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/52304/net-library-for-running-an-embedded-selfhosted-light-web-server-from-c-with-ss